# Convert the XML node value to date

Tags: java, xml, date

Can I know how to convert the "`2016-02-25T07:05:22.0Z`" to "`yyyyMMddHHmmssS`" and then into "`yyyyDDDHHmmssS`" format.

I have tried the below code:

```
String test = "2016-02-25T07:05:22.0Z";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssS");
Date date = formatter.parse(how to pass the test value);
System.out.println(date);
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

For the above case output value should be "`20160560705220`".

The functionality is like from one of the application the 20160560705220 will get converted to "`yyyyDDDHHmmssS`" and then to "`'yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.S''Z'`" as passed as response to request soap xml.

```
  DECLARE rInHeader REFERENCE TO     rEnvXmlNsc.UISInqSubscriberResponse.*:Envelope.*:Header;
              IF rInHeader.*:CESInformation.*:SubscriberContextIdentifier <>   '' THEN
                    SET rOutMember.ct:MemberEffectiveTimestamp =    CAST(CAST(CAST(CAST(rInHeader.*:CESInformation.*:SubscriberContextIdentifier AS DECIMAL) AS CHARACTER) AS TIMESTAMP FORMAT 'yyyyDDDHHmmssS') AS CHARACTER FORMAT 'yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.S''Z');
              END IF;
```

Now I need this part of the code to get converted to "20160560705220" on my end.

Can any one help one this one.

Comment: What is the error here? You cannot get it converted?

Comment: Are you sure date 60 ? may be on mars

Comment: I have edit the question. The problem is here is how to convert the test string into date format. Whether I have to remove the T and Z values from the string and then convert to date?

Comment: @bharathi do you want time zone i.e Z ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String test = "2016-02-25T07:05:22.0Z";
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssS");
    SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.'0Z'");

    Date date = null;
    try
    {
        date = formatter2.parse(test);
    }
    catch (ParseException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

Comment: Posted answer at same time, deleted mine